# Google Script Library sourcing another Library to alleviate versioning

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I’m trying to deploy a GAS script library to over a dozen spreadsheets (and growing) and so far I have been referencing the main library and having to go in and update the VERSION number of the sourced library on every spreadsheet. That is becoming untenable.

I had the brilliant idea of having all of the spreadsheets point to a “middle man” script library and only have to update the middleman’s version of the main library that it was sourcing.

Debugging showed me that even though I’d version up changes to the main library and source the new version in the middleman, the spreadsheet children would still be pointing to old versions of the main library... unless I version up the middleman and then point the children to that new version of the middleman - which brings me back to the same unbearable issue.

Does anyone have a solution to this issue of pushing out new changes to multiple child spreadsheets without having to version up each one of them?

Comment: How do you reference the scripts in each child sheet.  It sounds reminiscent of a caching issue where you could work around that in the old school way of adding a current time parameter to the url.  Perhaps if you embed a script that dynamically adds the required source including the timestamp to ensure that it gets a fresh copy?  I'm just guessing though, since I don't know how you are doing it on your end.

Comment: I’m setting the reference to the library in the spreadsheet script RESOURCES - using the project key of the libary and having to set a version number for that library.  .. I should also mention that these spreadsheets and their scripts are being executed by multiple users, who I don’t want to give edit priveleges of the script to - just read-only.

Comment: You might want to consider using an Unlisted add-on.  All new publications of a new add-on deployment are updated automatically.  An Unlisted add-on does not need to go through the review and approval process.  Another alternative, would be to set the button to Development mode, and only update the library when you are sure that you want to deploy that code.  In other words, never use the library for development.  Have a separate development version.  Then you'd need a tool to overwrite the library from the development version, or copy and paste.  Another option is to update the manifest file

Comment: which can be done with code.  There is a library that you can install, to do that.  [Git Hub link](https://github.com/tanaikech/ManifestsApp)  There is also a good blog post about the manifest file:  [Link to blog post](https://mashe.hawksey.info/2017/11/everything-you-always-wanted-to-know-about-google-apps-script-manifest-files-but-were-afraid-to-ask/#Managing_manifest_files_with_ManifestApp)